# Capture picture from WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to listen for WebView page load full completed and then capture screenshot of loaded page?

I tried two ways, but they both not working:

- using `WebViewClient` and `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`.
  It doesn't work (and it described in docs) because Picture may be not ready it this moment
- using `WebView.PictureListener` and `onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture)`
  It also doesn't solve problem, because this method calls undetermined times. At first time, picture often contains only part of page content. And I don't know way how determine, that the current call is last for the page.

I want to notice, that the problem is to find right moment to make screenshot, and not how it can be done.

Comment: Visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942623/which-can-replace-capturepicture-function/52929553#52929553

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Note that since I answered this, onNewPicture has been deprecated (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html and [What does "This method is deprecated" mean for application developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers)). Unfortunately, there is no information on what replaces it, or at what API levels it was supported. I guess that means that you use this at your own risk.]

I think you’re correct that onNewPicture is the right place to capture a screenshot of a loaded WeView page, but also correct that it is hard to know when to actually do the capture.

It appears that WebView calls onNewPicture whenever there has been any drawing. For example, it calls onNewPicture repeatedly when the search bar is in keyboard entry mode and the cursor is flicking. Similarly, for some web pages (eg www.yelp.com/nyc) it calls onNewPicture repeatedly, even after the page has finished drawing, probably because of the flashing cursor in the Search box. But at the other extreme it will call onNewPicture only once (eg if the user drops down an iGoogle item).

So there’s no easy rule? The approach we’ve taken is to

- monitor a range of events that are involved / affect page loading – such as shouldOverrideUrl, onPageFinished, focus changes, scrolling start/end, in addition to onNewPicture
- run a  timer (2secs is working well) on onNewPicture, reset by a new onNewPicture
- implement a page loading FSM which uses the events and timer expiry as inputs, and moves through a series of state/action transitions, to the point where it decides it genuinely has a new picture.

Not pretty, but it works, with very few cases where it captures the same picture twice – and no cases where it fails to capture a picture where it should.

Comment: Sorry. An FSM is a Finite State Machine - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine.

Comment: There's also a reference in that article to SourceForge resources.

The idea is that you set up your own FSM to handle page loading where
-- the inputs are either events like a call to onNewPicture or a timeout expiry
-- the states depend the behavior you want, but would be things like "initialised", "waiting on onNewPicture etc.
-- for each input/state combination the implementation either moves to a new state or takes some action - with the final action being to  do the capture.

Comment: @Torid `onNewPicture` is now [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449210/what-does-this-method-is-deprecated-mean-for-application-developers). Can you update your answer accordingly? With some elaboration on the FSM logic? (code or pseudo-code would be super). +1.

Comment: Given that there is apparently no replacement for onNewPicture, it is hard to imagine what an alternative approach might be. I've updated my answer above to mention that it is deprecated and point to an00b's post.