# Taking a Layout screenshot, WebView not visable in it

Tags: android

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a layout that contains several webview using this code.

```
LinearLayout v = LinLayList.get(0);
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);         
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
v.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

But here's what I'm getting ( layout is above and the screenshot is below ).

[image]

While the textviews with "AAAAA!" appear fine in the screenshot, the webview seem to be missing.

Any ideas what might have caused it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Web view is not a simple view, I don't sure 100% but maybe you can't take screenshot form web view in standart way. This may help you :

[Capture picture from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538429/capture-picture-from-webview)